# Sending variable by http get

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-http

I have problem with sending variable by http.get, can someone correct me?

```
$http.get("/product/products", { 'quantity': 5 }).then(function (resp) {
    $scope.products = resp.data;
})
```

Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

You should be sending it as `params` property of config object.

```
$http.get("/product/products", { params: { 'quantity': 5 }})
```

Comment: If i want to took it in node so i must do:
  console.log(req.params); or   console.log(req.body); ??

Comment: But console.log return me empty {} when i use req.body or req.params

Comment: @Turqus as you haven't mentioned a parameter in route, you should be doing `req.query` instead

Answer (score 0):

cant send a request body for `get` request. you can either change it to a `POST` request or send the variable as `params`

```
$http.get("/product/products", { params: { 'quantity': 5 }}).then(function (resp) {
    $scope.products = resp.data;
})
```